# Can we do nil or NULL in dealloc method and releasing that variable?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [refreshProgressInd release];
    [DetailsObject release];
      List=nil;
    [List release];
    [mapView release];
     addAnnotation=nil;
    [addAnnotation release];
    [reverseGeocoder release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't set a variable to `nil` *before* releasing it, otherwise the `release` message gets discarded when it should have been sent to an object.

```
[someObject release];
someObject = nil;
```

Keep in mind that `dealloc` is the last thing to be invoked before your object is actually deallocated, so setting variables to `nil` is often unnecessary.